# Why no inheritance relations between the C++ <mutex> mutex'es?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, inheritance, mutex, idioms

The C++ standard library has the following four classes [defined in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/mutex) :

- [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)
- [std::timed_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex)
- [std::recursive_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex)
- [std::timed_recursive_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_timed_mutex)

One would assume there would be a diamond of inheritance relations between these four classes, or that recursivity and timed'ness would be abstract base classes. Why is neither of these the case? **Edit:** Is it just the performance consideration or is there something about the semantics which I'm missing?

Comment: What benefit would inheritance provide?

Comment: @T.C.: Semantic clarity. Also, runtime rather than compile-time polymorphism with base class function pointers. I'm not saying these are huge benefits, I'm just asking whether the reason nothing inherits anything because is performance.

Comment: A class hierarchy forces `timed_mutex` to have the same members as `mutex`. But the implementation of those two classes could be entirely different. To accommodate for this, you'd have to define them as interfaces, with relation between those interfaces. Interface => pure virtual functions => no proper value semantics. (Not sure if you could hide the data members via a PIMPL managed only by the most-derived type.)

Answer (score 4):

Virtual functions and inheritance have runtime implications, including cost.

In C++, the rule is that you don't pay for what you don't use.  If there was such inheritance, the cost would be put on all users, even users who didn't need the inheritance.

If you need such inheritance, you can erase down to the concepts of Lockable, BasicLockable, etc.  This could be useful if you wanted to (say) accept any Lockable type to be passed to a function, and within it lock the type.

Here is a class that can store any `BasicLockable` type:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};

struct lockable {
  struct iimpl {
    virtual ~iimpl() {}
    virtual void lock() = 0;
    virtual void unlock() = 0;
    virtual bool try_lock() = 0;
  };
  template<class M>
  struct impl {
    M m;
    virtual void lock() override { m.lock(); }
    virtual void unlock() override { m.unlock(); }
    virtual bool try_lock() override { return m.try_lock(); }
  };
  std::unique_ptr<iimpl> pimpl;
  template<class M, class...Args>
  lockable( tag<M>, Args&&...args ):
    pimpl( new impl<M>{ {std::forward<Args>(args)...} } )
  {} 
  lockable(lockable&&)=default;
  lockable& operator=(lockable&&)=default;
  lockable()=default;
  explicit operator bool() const { return static_cast<bool>(pimpl); }
  void lock() { pimpl->lock(); }
  void unlock() override { pimpl->unlock(); }
  bool try_lock() override { return pimpl->try_lock(); }
};
```

which lets you have a function taking one of any of the `mutex` types.  In practice, you probably want a `lockable_view`, which is non owning:

```
struct lockable_view {
  void* pmutex = nullptr;
  struct vtable {
    void(*lock)(void*);
    void(*unlock)(void*);
    bool(*try_lock)(void*);
    template<class M>
    static impl const* get_table() {
      static const impl t={
        [](void* m){static_cast<M*>(m)->lock();},
        [](void* m){static_cast<M*>(m)->unlock();},
        [](void* m)->bool{return static_cast<M*>(m)->try_lock();}
      };
      return &t;
    }
  };
  vtable const* pimpl=nullptr;
  template<class M>
  lockable_view( M&& m ):
    pmutex( std::addressof(m) ),
    pimpl( vtable::get_table<std::decay_t<M>>() )
  {} 
  lockable_view(lockable&&)=default;
  lockable_view& operator=(lockable_view&&)=default;
  lockable_view()=default;
  explicit operator bool() const { return static_cast<bool>(pimpl); }
  void lock() { pimpl->lock(pmutex); }
  void unlock() { pimpl->unlock(pmutex); }
  bool try_lock() { return pimpl->try_lock(pmutex); }
};
```

which is analogous to taking a `std::mutex&` if it where virtual.  It uses a different type erasure technique (to avoid a needless allocation).  I basically create a manual vtable, and store a pointer to it in `pimpl`.

There are some efforts to make this kind of type erasure easier in future versions of C++.  As you can see, it is currently a bit of a pain.

Comment: This is quite interesting, especially `std::decay_t` which I did not know about, so +1. However - are you saying that the only reason for the lack of inheritance is performance, and that if the penalty was inconsequential the inheritance would be in place?

Comment: @einpok I cannot guarentee that, but it is a sufficient reason.  I believe that *nothing* in `std` outside of io uses inheritance/virtual functions in its interface.  I may have missed something, but `std` is aimed to provide hand coded C-level performance with high level abstraction and safety: virtual functions do not qualify.  Also note that `std` io ... well, sucks, performance wise.

Comment: How do I call `try_lock_until` using this design?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Which design, the `lockable_view` one?  You write a `timed_lockable_view` class that also exposed that method?  You could reduce code duplication by messing up how the `vtable` is constructed (splitting allocation from initialization, and exploiting layout-compatibility, etc) if you really want.

Comment: Well, I still want to know whether there's another reason beside performance... edited the question accordingly. Thanks, though.

Comment: @howard or do you mean the template problem?  Marshal the template function call to nanoseconds or somesuch.

Comment: No, I just meant:  If we're going to derive `timed_mutex` from `mutex`, how do you use those functions that cause you to want a `timed_mutex` in the first place?  You can't go through the base class because there is no such API in the base class.  Thus the derivation has added no value, and cost you both space and time.  Benefit/cost ratio is less than one.

Comment: @howard ah: 2nd party provides mutex for 1st party to lock.  2nd party can provide either timed or untimed mutex, and interact with full type.  1st party does not care what kind of mutex they have.  Currently, `lockable_view` would let you do this: inheritance would also let you do this.  However, runtime cost of `lockable_view` <= cost of inheritance, and only those who use it pay for it.  And use case is a corner one.

Comment: @Yakk:  I see, thanks.  `lockable_view` is a good tool for the use case you describe.  I was fixated on the title of this question.